# Unable to boot after upgrade 15.04=>15.10 "Failed to start Set console keymap."

Tags: boot, upgrade, keyboard, 15.10, keyboard-layout

After upgrading to 15.10 my system boots up the the following output:

```
[Failed] Failed to start Set console keymap.
See 'systemctl status console-setup.service' for details

[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Start NTP daemon.
See 'systemctl status console-setup.service' for details
```

I have a Finnish keyboard on a Macbook which now has switched over to U.S. english. I have been fiddling with Xmodmap and debconf keyboard settings prior to the upgrade. Afterwards when the keyboard was set to U.S. English I attempted to change the keyboard configuration via the command line and after a reboot the system doesn't boot properly.
There isn't much discussion on the topic elsewhere and I'm completely stuck on what to do.

Comment: …and this is what was in console-setup.service:   ```Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/console-setup.service: static; vendor preset: enabled)    Active: inactive (dead)    Docs: man:loadkeys(1)```